# Group by only by one field and use another fields in select without aggregation

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have a view that gets data from different tables and views and returns it grouped.

Here is the code of view

```
 CREATE VIEW analysis.vwOnboardingTableData
AS
SELECT USC.UseCaseCapabilityId,
       USC.Name,
       USC.JobId,
       USC.Id                                AS UseCaseId,
       COUNT(JSOR.SupplierKey)               AS SupplierCount,
       JSOR.OnboardingRouteId,
       SUM(JS.SupplierPaymentDocCount)       AS PaymentsCount,
       SUM(JS.SupplierInvoiceDocCount)       AS InvoicesCount,
       SUM(JS.SupplierPurchaseOrderDocCount) AS PoCount,
       SUM(JS.SupplierSpendValueCurrencyJob) AS Spend,
       JM.JobSpendSource
FROM analysis.UseCases AS USC
         INNER JOIN analysis.UseCaseSupplierStates AS JSOR
                    ON USC.Id = JSOR.UseCaseId
                        AND USC.JobId = JSOR.JobId
         INNER JOIN analysis.vwJobSupplierWithScores AS JS
                    ON JSOR.SupplierKey = JS.SupplierKey
         INNER JOIN analysis.vwJobMetrics AS JM
                    ON USC.JobId = JM.JobId
WHERE (USC.IsTemplate = 0)
  AND (JSOR.IsQualified = 1)
GROUP BY JSOR.OnboardingRouteId,
         USC.Name,
         USC.JobId,
         JM.JobSpendSource,
         USC.UseCaseCapabilityId, USC.Id
go
```

For now, it is grouped by multiple fields to get those fields in SELECT. I need to group it only by `USC.UseCaseCapabilityId` and get the same fields without any aggregating functions like `SUM`, etc.

How I can achieve this?

Comment: Make it easy to assist you - simplify! Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (no images, no links.)

Comment: BTW, your tables have _columns_, not fields.

Comment: I think the problem is clear from the view  code. I need to group by  `UseCaseCapabilityId` and use ` USC.Name,`  without any function like `SUM` or `COUNT`

For now, if I delete it from group by it will show me this

`Column 'USC.Name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause` @jarlh

Comment: Long story short - You can't. If you have multiple different values for `USC.Name` for the same value of `UseCaseCapabilityId`, then how would SQL Server know which one to show if you don't give it any kind of indication? You can use `MAX` or `MIN` on a string field to bring back the first or last value, but whatever you do you have to give some kind of indication of how to choose a single value where there a multiple possibilities.

Comment: If you were to provide a little more information about the relationships and the structure of your tables, it may be possible to suggest alternative approaches. From the information you have provided @GarethD answer is the only solution.